# Navigation bar is missing in my launching screen of drawer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6

I am making one iOS app in which i am using MMDrawer. The problem is that the tool bar in which my drawer button is not showing. I can't even find navigation bar in that screen through which i want to show side drawer menu.

I am initialising drawer by following code in my login screen button

```
AppDelegate *aPPDel=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIViewController * leftSideDrawerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sidemenuvc"];

UINavigationController * leftSideNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:leftSideDrawerViewController];

UIViewController * centerSideDrawerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homevc"];

UINavigationController * centerSideNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:centerSideDrawerViewController];
MMDrawerController *drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerSideNavController  leftDrawerViewController:leftSideNavController];
[leftSideDrawerViewController.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
 [centerSideDrawerViewController.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
[drawerController setShowsShadow:NO];

[drawerController setMaximumRightDrawerWidth:200.0];
[drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
[drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:drawerController];
[aPPDel.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

in my home screen toolbar button, i wrote this code

```
[self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I tried all possible ways to show navigation bar by( hidden no ) also but couldn't find solution